Mixed content alert with google chrome when I visit my web site that uses action cable on Heroku
I am building a chat app on heroku using Action cable. No warnings are generated immediately after visiting the site. After sending a message, the following warning appears in Google chrome's developer tools once that message is drawn on the screen. Also, on smartphones, the warning symbol appears next to the URL.
Mixed content alert with google chrome
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element '<URL>'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see <URL>
862:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://[my app url]' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://[asset url]'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html

The warning symbol on smartphone

About heroku-redis
plan: mini
version: 7.2.4

About redis gem
version: 4.2.5

About ruby
version: 3.1.6

About rails
version: 6.1.4

I implemented it with the following reference using ruby on rails.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis#connecting-in-ruby
config/initializers/redis.rb
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"], ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })

config/cable.yml
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: myapp_production
  ssl_params:
    verify_mode: <%= OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE %>

